# How can I interpret the pandas quartiles?

Tags: pandas, quantile, quartile

I have a pandas datafram `df` with a column `A`. The values of `A` are based on predictions and I've forced them to be greater or equal to 0.00000001.
Now when I run `df.A.describe()` I get:

```
count    3.900000e+02
mean     1.047049e-05
std      7.774749e-05
min      1.000000e-08
25%      1.000000e-08
50%      1.000000e-08
75%      1.000000e-08
max      1.008428e-03+
```

The way I understand it, this means that at least 75% of my values for A are equal to 0.0000001.
However, when I run `x = len(df.loc[df['A'] == 0.00000001])` I get `x = 207` and 207/390 < 0.75.
Shouldn't I get a value for x that is greater than 292 (390*0.75 = 292.5)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who might be running into a similar problem, I've found the answer:
There are only 207 values in my df with df.A == 0.00000001. However there are also some values which are just marginally bigger (e.g. maybe df.A == 0.0000000100000000001). Hence, even though those values are not exactly equal to 0.00000001, when I print the df or ask for `df.A.describe()` they are shown as 0.00000001, since the difference is so small.